# Cookie writes on non exist file and it work. why?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I work with CURL and me need to grab some key on this [page][1]

And when I used file for write and read cookie
like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '1.tmp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'1.tmp');
```

It's works for me. But this file not exist.
When I change name - it work too, but when I change path like "tmp/1.tmp" - it's wrong.
Why?

Comment: `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options must be set with **absolute** path value. `"cookie.txt"` is a **relative** path.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` will create the cookie file if it doesn't exist. But it won't create a directory automatically. So `1.tmp` will create the file in the current directory, but `tmp/1.tmp` requires that the `tmp` subdirectory already exists.

You can use `mkdir("tmp")` first to allow `tmp/1.tmp` to work.

Comment: Ok. but tmp directory is exist. but it not work too.